# How can I assign a data type decimal to a column in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm working with postgresql-9.1 recently.

For some reason I have to use a tech which does not support data type numeric but decimal. Unfortunately, the data type of columns which I've assigned decimal to them in my Postgresql are always numeric. I tried to alter the type, but it did not work though I've got the messages just like "Query returned successfully with no result in 12 ms".

SO, I want to know how can I get the columns to be decimal.

Any help will be highly appreciate.

e.g.

My creating clauses:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS htest
(
  dsizemin decimal(8,3) NOT NULL,
  dsizemax decimal(8,3) NOT NULL,
  hidentifier character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  tgrade character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  fdvalue decimal(8,3),
  CONSTRAINT htest_pkey PRIMARY KEY (dsizemin , dsizemax , hidentifier , tgrade )
);
```

My altering clauses:

```
ALTER TABLE htest
ALTER COLUMN dsizemin TYPE decimal(8,3);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: ["The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL). Is the problem that this tool asks the database for the table's schema and doesn't understand the `numeric` that comes back when you create a `decimal` column?

Comment: `decimal` is just an alias for `numeric` to keep programs written for Oracle a little bit happier. It doesn't look like you can make it a "real" alias with a `DOMAIN`, so I suspect you're out of luck unless you can make the program cope with the table metadata showing `numeric` where it expects `decimal`. Try `SELECT '1'::decimal;` to see what I mean.

Comment: to @muistooshort:Yeah, the tool does not understand numeric, so sad.

Comment: to @Craig Ringer: It just show nemuric. May be I have to try anther way. Thank you both.

Comment: Is this an in-house tool? If not, what tool is it? Can you fix it or manually configure it or is it so friendly and helpful that you can't make it behave sensibly?

Comment: to @muistooshort : Hi. It's a SemanticWeb API with concern the data in database. It seems that I've messed up the mapping between the migration of data from MySQL to Postgresql. Now I've fixed it, and it works. Thank you after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, "decimal" is an alias for "numeric" which poses some problems when your app thinks it expects a type called "decimal" from the database.   As Craig noted above, you can't even create a domain called "decimal"

There is no good workaround in the database side.  The only thing you can do is change the application to expect a numeric data type back.

Answer (score 3):

Use Numeric (precision, scale) to store decimals
precision represents the total number of expected digits on either side of the decimal point. scale is the number decimals you wish to store.

This Numeric (5,5) would imply you only want numbers less than 1 (negative or positive) with 5 decimal points. Debug, it may be Numeric (6,5) if the postgre sql errors out because it things the leading 0 is a decimal.

0.12345 would be an example of the above.

1.12345 would need a field Numeric (6,5)
100.12345 would need a field Numeric (8,5)
-100.12345 would need a field Numeric (8,5)

When you write a select statement to see the decimals, it rounds to 2; but if you do something like Select 100 * [field] from [table], then extra decimals should start appearing....

Comment: (6,5) etc explanation was really helpful!